# Magento 2 : how to create dynamic filed in admin system configuration?

Tags: magento2, admin, configuration, system-config, drop-downs

I want a multi-select drop down in system configuration with dynamic field.
So How to create ?
**Please check this image.**

[image]

Comment: There is a good document on here for dynamic rows on system configs https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ext-best-practices/tutorials/dynamic-row-system-config.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can acheive this by implementing like Below code :

Add below code in your system.xml file.

> **app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\adminhtml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../Magento/Backend/etc/system_file.xsd">
<system>
  <tab id="extension" translate="label" sortOrder="100">
     <label>My Extension Configuration</label>
  </tab>
  <section id="extension" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
     <label>Add Dynamic Row Multiselect</label>
     <tab>extension</tab>
     <resource>Vendor_Extension::extension</resource>
     <group id="quantity_ranges" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label> Add Dynamic Row Multiselect </label>
            <field id="ranges" translate="label" sortOrder="5" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Dynamic Field</label>
                <frontend_model>Vendor\Extension\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field\Groups</frontend_model>
                <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Serialized\ArraySerialized</backend_model>
            </field>
        </group>
  </section>
</system>
```

Now, we have to create one more file “Groups.php” inside the Block folder.

> **app\code\Vendor\Extension\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field\Groups.php**

```
    <?php
    namespace Vendor\Extension\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field;
    
    use Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\FieldArray\AbstractFieldArray;
    use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
    use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
    
    class Groups extends AbstractFieldArray
    {
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockInterface
         */
        protected $paymentMethod;
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockInterface
         */
        protected $customerGpRenderer;
    
        protected function _prepareToRender()
        {
            // For Customer Groups
            $this->addColumn('customer_gp', [
                'label' => __('Customer Group'),
                'renderer' => $this->getCustomerGpRenderer(),
                'extra_params' => 'multiple="multiple"'
            ]);
    
            // For Payment Methods
            $this->addColumn('payment_method', [
                'label' => __('Payment Method'),
                'renderer' => $this->getPaymentRenderer(),
                'extra_params' => 'multiple="multiple"'
            ]);
    
            $this->_addAfter = false;
            $this->_addButtonLabel = __('Add');
        }
    
        protected function _prepareArrayRow(DataObject $row)
        {
            $options = [];
            $paymentMethods = $row->getPaymentMethod();
            $customerGps = $row->getCustomerGp();
            if (count($paymentMethods) > 0) {
                foreach ($paymentMethods as $method) {
                    $options['option_' . $this->getPaymentRenderer()->calcOptionHash($method)]
                        = 'selected="selected"';
                }
            }
    
            if (count($customerGps) > 0) {
                foreach ($customerGps as $gp) {
                    $options['option_' . $this->getCustomerGpRenderer()->calcOptionHash($gp)]
                        = 'selected="selected"';
                }
            }
            $row->setData('option_extra_attrs', $options);
        }
    
        protected function getPaymentRenderer()
        {
           
            if (!$this->paymentMethod) {
            $this->paymentMethod = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                \Vendor\Extension\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field\PaymentMethodColumn::class,
                '',
                ['data' => ['is_render_to_js_template' => true]]
            );
        }
        return $this->paymentMethod;
        }
    
        protected function getCustomerGpRenderer()
        {
            if (!$this->customerGpRenderer) {
               $this->customerGpRenderer = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                \Vendor\Extension\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field\CustomerGpColumn::class,
                '',
                ['data' => ['is_render_to_js_template' => true]]
            );
            }
            return $this->customerGpRenderer;
        }
    }
```

Now, Create “PaymentMethodColumn.php” inside the same Block folder.

> **app\code\Vendor\Extension\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field\PaymentMethodColumn.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Select;

class PaymentMethodColumn extends Select
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    private $_appConfigScopeConfigInterface;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Payment\Model\Config
     */
    private $_paymentModelConfig;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Payment\Model\Config $paymentModelConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $appConfigScopeConfigInterface,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_appConfigScopeConfigInterface = $appConfigScopeConfigInterface;
        $this->_paymentModelConfig = $paymentModelConfig;
    }

    public function setInputName($value)
    {
        return $this->setName($value . '[]');
    }

    public function _toHtml(): string
    {
        if (!$this->getOptions()) {
            $this->setOptions($this->getPaymentMethods());
        }
        $this->setExtraParams('multiple="multiple"');
        return parent::_toHtml();
    }

    public function getPaymentMethods()
    {
        $payments = $this->_paymentModelConfig->getActiveMethods();
        $methods = [];
        foreach ($payments as $paymentCode => $paymentModel) {
            $paymentTitle = $this->_appConfigScopeConfigInterface
                ->getValue('payment/'.$paymentCode.'/title');
            $methods[] = array(
                'value' => $paymentCode,
                'label' => $paymentTitle
            );
        }
        return $methods;
    }
}
```

Lastly Create "CustomerGpColumn.php" inside the same Block folder.

> **app\code\Vendor\Extension\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field\CUstomerGpColumn.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Select;

class CustomerGpColumn extends Select
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Collection
     */
    private $customerGp;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Collection $customerGp,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->customerGp = $customerGp;
    }

    public function setInputName($value)
    {
        return $this->setName($value . '[]');
    }

    public function _toHtml(): string
    {
        if (!$this->getOptions()) {
            $this->setOptions($this->getCustomerGps());
        }
        $this->setExtraParams('multiple="multiple"');
        return parent::_toHtml();
    }

    public function getCustomerGps()
    {
        $gps = $this->customerGp->toOptionArray();
        return $gps;
    }
}
```

**After That Run the following commands :**

```
-> rm -rf generated/* var/cache/*
-> php bin/magento setup:di:compile
-> php bin/magento cache:flush
```

**Results :**
[image]

Comment: @rahulraj-vdc Have you tried the above code..?

Comment: sry but this is not working and plz get the payment method not country

Comment: @rahulrajvdc , Defenitely it will works, If you want the payment methods, I have updated my answer check it

Comment: hello sir how to create in shipping  dynamic  filed

Comment: @rahulrajvdc, according to your question : I want a multi-select drop down in system configuration with dynamic field
I have given the answer. "in shipping", Please elaborate more or edit your question and explain exactly what issue you are facing.

Comment: hello sir dynmic filed select data not save in database

Comment: @rahulrajvdc, I have modified the file : app\code\Vendor\Extension\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field\Groups.php
update that and then check it.

Please accept my answer, if it works for you